# qiskit-aer-gpu: cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: gpu, nvidia, ubuntu-20.04, qiskit

My GPU is:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
     product: GK107 [GeForce GT 740]
     vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
     version: a1
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
     resources: irq:41 memory:e6000000-e6ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:8000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

which has CC of 3.0. I have installed cuda version 10.1 (requirement for [qiskit-aer-gpu](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer#installing-gpu-support) which as far I have searched is compatible with Compute capability of 3.0.

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Drivers are also properly installed:

```
nvidia_uvm           1200128  2
nvidia_drm             65536  7
nvidia_modeset       1200128  11 nvidia_drm
nvidia              35491840  550 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        307200  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   618496  11 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
```

However after installing qiskit-aer-gpu, when I run a simple code using gpu

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import *
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
sim = AerSimulator(method='statevector', device='GPU')
shots = 100
depth=10
qubits = 25
circuit = transpile(QuantumVolume(qubits, depth, seed=0),
backend=sim,
optimization_level=0)
circuit.measure_all()
result = execute(circuit,sim,shots=shots,seed_simulator=12345).result()
```

it says:

```
Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
ERROR:  [Experiment 0] for_each: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

Now what is the actual reason behind error? Is there any version compatibility issue?

Comment: That error means whatever you are trying to use has been built without any binary support for your GPU architecture. This isn’t a software version problem, it is hardware incompatibility

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using a GPU based off of Nvidia's Kepler architecture. This architecture only has partial support for CUDA 10.1, so this is probably your issue.

Comment: If you think you've got the issue pinned down you can also suggest a solution